# Add Description Blogger

Tags: blogger

I wonder how do I add the blog description in my template specific location.

```
<data:blog.description />
```

Returns nothing. How do I get the description of the blog?

Answer (score 1):

it may helps you..

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' itemprop='description'/>
<b:else/>
<!-- Show if the Meta Description post Page is not active-->
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName + &quot; - &quot; your customized meta description here .&quot;' name='description'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Hi, actually I like the description of the site, placed there in a `DIV`. But in this particular location on the site does not work the call shown above, it returns nothing.
https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=pt-BR#header

Comment: You can do this by 2 methods.

Method 1: First find the blog description div tag then change the style code of that div.
Ex: margin-left: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding options

Method 2: Assign the class name for the div which you would to re-possion and call it anywhere from the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<data:blog.metaDescription/>` instead of `<data:blog.description/>`. look at this

```
 <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/> | <data:blog.metaDescription/></title> 
<b:else/>
<title><data:blog.pageName/> | <data:blog.title/></title>
</b:if>
```

I hope it helps